# Error message on blog posts only on my local environment

Tags: database, htaccess, server

I copied all my WP files from the server to my local WAMP as a dev-environment. 
Everything works smoothly except when viewing a blog post.

I get a good output of all the titles/categories/post-content/ect' - But with a strange output before the blogs content:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

content.php Line 68 is this part in the code: `__(  ),`

One line after "the_content" function:

```
<div class="post-bottom">
    <div class="post-text-container">
        <?php
            /* translators: %s: Name of current post*/
            $postURL = get_permalink();
            $commentsURL = get_comments_link();
            the_content( sprintf(
                __(  ),
                the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )
            ) );
            if ( !is_single() ) :
                    echo "<div class=\"read-more\"><a href=\"$postURL\">Continue reading...</a> | <a href=\"$commentsURL\">Full Comments</a></div>";
                endif;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

What can be the cause of this?

Edit: the only things that I changed when coping stuff to my local server were:

1 - I copied my database to my local phpmyadmin and changed all `http://www.example.com` to `http://localhost/example` in the options table.

2 - I totally removed my .htaccess file (and wordpress generated a new one by it self)

This is how the one on the server looks:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and this is what I have locally:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

3- I enabled "rewrite_modle" on WAMP because it's disabled by default.

Comment: Check with the PHP versions of WAMP and your live server. Both are same or different?

Comment: Your question is a generic PHP question and not specific with WordPress. The funciton `__()` always needs one argument and that is what the error says: the argument is missing. The error is a "Warning" type ([E_WARNING](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)) and usually production servers are configured to not show that of errors as they usually doesn't make the program to fail. So, the configuration may be different in the two servers, that's all.

Comment: Just because you copy pasted it from somewhere else, doesn't mean that it wasn't already broken. You probably took it from a place that didn't have xdebug set up, or error logging turned on and never noticed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is regarding the following part of your code:  `__( )`.

In WP `__` is actually a function for translation purposes.

From a short look [in the manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2), we can see that the `__()` function usage is:

```
<?php $translated_text = __( $text, $domain ); ?>
```

And that the `$text` parameter is required.

> $text (string) (required) Text to translate. Default: None $domain
>
> (string) (optional) Domain to retrieve the translated text. Default:
>   'default'

In your code, you don't send any argument to that function and therefore you're getting a legit warning. To be honest, I don't know why there was no argument in the first place. Moreover, also your remote server should show that warning. In case it doesn't - or the code is different or you have `error_reporting(0)` somewhere on the server (php.ini / wp-config.php).

A simple solution would be just to add an empty string as an argument.

Comment: Either replacing `__()` with  `'%s'` will do the trick, or replacing the whole call with just `the_content();`